# OnChange not being rendered in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have the following component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" 
                access="global" >
    <input type="text" name="Name" class="slds-input" value="Test" onChange="{!c.doSomething}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doSomething : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('test');
    }
})
```

When i change the value of the input, "doSomething" is not triggered.
the html looks like this:

```
<div data-aura-rendered-by="420:0" class="flexipageComponent" data-aura-class="flexipageComponent">
             <input class="slds-input" type="text" name="Name" data-aura-rendered-by="424:0"> 
</div>
```

looks like onChange is not even rendered, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think there is a typo, `onchange` 'c' is in small case, can you try that?

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: Hi Dana, I tried same code with `onchange` in small case and it worked. Yes it was not rendered in html because lightning remove and minifies it into a seperate JS file

Comment: i had a typo, you are correct. im sorry
will delete this question

Comment: Keep it as it is.. It would help, other in case they searched

Comment: so post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onchange` actually is all in small-case. So your code will be

```
 <input type="text" name="Name" class="slds-input" value="Test" onchange="{!c.doSomething}"/>
```

Also, You could not find `onchange` in rendered dom as lightning locker minifies and moves the JS in a different file so that it cant be altered easily.

src: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp